# Get absolute URL path using bash in linux

Tags: linux, bash, url, console, absolute

There is a relative URL. For example bstu.by. How to get the absolute URL path through bash? Use of any console utilities linux is allowed.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

use `readlink` utility

```
readlink -f bstu.by
```

this can also be used to resolve path binaries with use of `which` as below

`readlink -f 'which java'`  please use ` instead of '

Comment: You can use `readlink -f $(which java)` which is basically the same.

Answer (score -1):

Use `realpath`:

```
NAME
       realpath - print the resolved path

SYNOPSIS
       realpath [OPTION]... FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       Print the resolved absolute file name; all but the last component must exist
```

Example:

```
/etc$ realpath passwd
/etc/passwd
```

Note that it also resolves symlinks, so the resulting filename may not be the same:

```
/bin$ realpath awk
/usr/bin/gawk
```